# What is a good strategy for creating a calendar that requires supervisor approval to post an event?

Tags: calendar, custom-form

I have been thrown into the Sharepoint deep end. My developer-side knowledge of the platform is limited, but I do have plenty of programming experience in general, so I'm confident that I can figure out how to do what I need to do. What I need here is a general strategy.

I have received a request to implement an "absence" calendar on a Sharepoint 2010 site which has permissions linked to the enterprise Active Directory. I can add and edit groups within this AD. The idea is that staff members will send a request to a supervisor to be absent. The supervisor approves or denies the request. Upon approval, the request is added to the calendar.

Here's the specific request:

There should be a dedicated "absence calendar." Users in a non-supervisor AD group would create a new event on this calendar to request time off. The form would contain a choice of supervisor, a start date and end date for the absence, and the type of absence (vacation, personal, medical leave). The post would not show up on the calendar immediately. Rather, the selected supervisor would receive an email with a link. If they click that link, the request is approved and the event is added to the calendar. Ideally the supervisor would receive a single email per request, and by clicking the link in the email they could either immediately approve the request or be taken to a dialog which would allow them to immediately approve the request.

Answer (score 2):

first make sure you  have activated workflows 2010 in site collection.

Now  first create a calendar list and go to its workflow settings (from ribbon) and create a workflow with approval and reject cases.

now by varying views in calendar list i.e, all items view, approved items view (shows only approved items based on workflow status code (16 for approved)condition  ) you may achieve above functionality. Then you need to make approved items view as default.

Then you can customize your calendar list form to your needs.

I don't think you can achieve above approval criteria with list infopath forms due to workflow process associated with it.

Comment: Awesome. I'm trying this out now.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to accomplish having the approval email be sent out to the selected supervisor? That seems to be the sticking point at the moment.

Comment: once you have created a calendar list --> workflow settings   --> Add a workflow -->Approval SharePoint 2010 -->specify name and Start options --> Next --> In Approvers select your Test Identity and verify its functionality.

Comment: You're helping me understand how Sharepoint works on a deeper level, and I really appreciate your help. I would vote up if I had the reputation. However, I wasn't specific enough in my initial question. I'm going to refine it a bit.